# Can not find password input object log in to google with selenium

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I am using `PhantomJS` in selenium for the driver. Here, I find that there is no problem inserting the email address. However, after clicking the next, there should have a input tag named 'password'. But, after waiting, I can not get the required 'password' tag. It shows error not finding the element. Sometimes, I am getting the following error (showing stacktrace):

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"
```

Since, I have waited enough time, the following code must work. 
Here is the below code snippet for working.

```
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");   
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("password"))); 
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
```

Here is the specific html showing the input field from the [google sign in page](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin) for email:

```
input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Email or phone" name="identifier" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value=""
```

The id of **Next** button is '**identifierNext**' and hhe hidden password field:

```
input type="password" name="hiddenPassword" jsname="RHeR4d" class="yb9KU" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
```

After inserting email and click on the next, the input field  for the password is:

```
input type="password" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-password" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your password" name="password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value=""
```

Now, the question is, I have used waiting mechanism for reloading the page so that I can get the password insertion page. But, using Selenium I can not find the named tag of 'password'.
I think the **click is not working properly**. Is there any chance of not working the click on **Next**?

Comment: is the password field is dynamic?

Comment: Why are you using `By.name` for the `password` field and `By.id` for the `passwordNext` field? Try both with `By.id`.

Comment: As pointed by @santhosh , If the field is dynamic, you should use xpath.

Comment: @Dalton I search in the html file and find that the input field for password has no id attribute, but has name attribute.

Comment: @santosh the input field is hidden at the first time when I insert for email. After clicking next the password field becomes visible.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the password field to become visible? Presence just means that it's in the DOM. That's generally not that useful... checking for visible or clickable is usually more useful.

Comment: @jeffC yes. I have added the wait. I have also used Thread.sleep() for 1 minutes. But, I do not get the result. Is there any problem I. click() on the identifier? I actually do not know how it works.

Comment: Edit your question and put also the HTML code responsible for this.

Comment: @Dalton I have edited the question

Comment: As I said before, you can use xpath, searching for //input[2] . This will get the second instance of the input field, which, in your case, is the password field. Try it and tell us.

Comment: @Dalton I have also tried the following snippet for waiting also:
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).se‌​ndKeys("**"); 
But having the same problem.
The Error message:
{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//input[@name='password']'","request":

Comment: Do not find by name. Try as I told you...

Comment: In my edited post, look at the last html snippet for the password input field. Here, only the name attribute is present and it value is 'password'. I think it will not work also for id. 
Besides, I have tried as you say driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).se‌​‌​ndKeys("**"); Still same issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150857/discussion-between-dalton-and-amee).

Comment: No. I said you to try `//input[2]` , not `//input[@id='password']` ... You did not do as I suggested.

Comment: Lets discuss in chat. Ok, that will be my mistake thinking about the first comment. Its also not working.

Comment: Try this: `By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")` . And I think `//input[1]` should also work (1 instead of 2 :).

Comment: I am getting this error message:
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"52","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-...

Comment: //input[1] works but can not find the element id of 'passwordNext' this time. The last line of the source code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the element id? Use xpath searching by elements instead of name or id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[1]"));
```

Or this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")));
WebElement elementpwd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I actuall do not know.. what is the main problem.. in PhantomJS. I can not get it worked using the above answer as well as my code. However, using the FirefoxDriver, I have successfully run the code. In PythonJS Driver still showing.. "Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers" OR, "Unable to find element with xpath ..."

Answer (score 0):

Please find the full code for sending email for Gmail using Selenium Web Driver using Chrome browser

```
public class Newtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Tharun\\Desktop\\work\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb_70']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'identifierId\']")).sendKeys("*******@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'identifierNext\']/content/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("*******");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'passwordNext\']/content/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbw\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':ir']/div/div")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#\\3a og")).sendKeys("*******@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#\\3a ny")).sendKeys("This is my selenium web driver automation code ");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\':p3\']")).sendKeys("This is my selenium web driver automation code ");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\':no\']")).click();
    }
}
```